# is Flutter bloc always must have one property(data)

Tags: flutter, mobile, bloc, cubit

I am worker for a project on flutter with bloc as state management.

But my screen contain a wide variety of data.

How can I management all this data?

```
class ProductCubit extends Cubit<ProductState> {
  Worker worker = Worker();
  List<ProductMakePriceChange> productsPriceChange = [];
  List<PurchaseCount> purchaseCount = [];
  int productCount = 0;
  int productSaleCount = 0;
  int productCategoryCount = 0;
  int productUnitCount = 0;
}
```

I have One state for each data (Loading state)
And One method for each data to load it

**The problem!**

when one state are change, all screen are rebuild

I need to change just one partition from my screen, just that partition when that data are effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

As you guessed correctly, you can of course move some fields to separate cubits. Another option would be to implement different subclasses of `ProductState` and check for the type in the `BlocBuilder` or `BlocConsumer` at runtime.

```dart
class ProductCubit extends Cubit<ProductState> {
  ProductCubit()
      : super(
          const ProductInitial(
            ProductInfo(
              productsPriceChange: [],
              purchaseCount: [],
              productSaleCount: 0,
              productCategoryCount: 0,
              productCount: 0,
              productUnitCount: 0,
            ),
          ),
        );

  Future<void> loadProductPurchaseCount() async {
    emit(ProductPurchaseCountLoadInProgress(state.productInfo));
    try {
      // TODO load product purchase count
      final productPurchaseCount = <dynamic>[];
      emit(
        ProductPurchaseCountLoadSuccess(
          state.productInfo.copyWith(
            purchaseCount: productPurchaseCount,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } catch (_) {
      emit(
        ProductPurchaseCountLoadSuccess(state.productInfo),
      );
    }
  }
}

abstract class ProductState extends Equatable {
  const ProductState(this.productInfo);

  final ProductInfo productInfo;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [productInfo];
}

class ProductInitial extends ProductState {
  const ProductInitial(ProductInfo productInfo) : super(productInfo);
}

class ProductPurchaseCountLoadInProgress extends ProductState {
  const ProductPurchaseCountLoadInProgress(ProductInfo productInfo)
      : super(productInfo);
}

class ProductPurchaseCountLoadFailure extends ProductState {
  const ProductPurchaseCountLoadFailure(ProductInfo productInfo)
      : super(productInfo);
}

class ProductPurchaseCountLoadSuccess extends ProductState {
  const ProductPurchaseCountLoadSuccess(ProductInfo productInfo)
      : super(productInfo);
}
```

Last, but not least, there is a relatively new Widget called `BlocSelector` which lets you check the state in order to determine whether the child should be built.

```dart
BlocSelector<BlocA, BlocAState, SelectedState>(
  selector: (state) {
    // return selected state based on the provided state.
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on the selected state.
  },
)
```

Check out the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc